# Write a function using native javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not that good in javascript functions. Please help me understand below code.

```
var num = 5; // i have a variable 5
    
Add 10; //returns 15
Add 23; //returns 28

The question is, how to create a function that,
if add 10 it will return 15
if add 23 it will return 28
```

Comment: I mean... come on....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything. If you don't learn anything, you get a degree you didn't earn that you use to get a job you can't perform.  If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help; they're being paid to teach you. Good luck.

Comment: no i dont  understand how to implement this one..

Comment: i want to know how you implement this

Comment: **You** implement this, not us. **If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help.**

Comment: If I knew there was a test on SO today I wouldn't have logged in

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for [**partial function in javascript**](http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/currying-and-partial-functions-in-javasc/231001821) which use the concept of closure.It is also known as [**currying-partials**](https://javascript.info/currying-partials)

```js
var add = number(5);

function number(x) {
  return function y(v) {
    return x + v;
  }
}


console.log(add(10));
console.log(add(23))
```

Comment: `the idea` - really? the idea? that's the **solution**, and all you did was nothing